# how to get substring from

Tags: bash, awk

how to get substring from

```
 42 45 47 49 4e 21 40 23 47 68 6a 6b 2c 47 68 6a BEGIN!@#Ghjk,Ghj 6b 45 4e 44 23 40 21 kEND#@!
```

to be

```
BEGIN!@#Ghjk,GhjkEND#@!
```

**Note:** there is whitespaces at  end of lines, I tried removing whitespaces at end of lines but I cant.

I tried

```bash
#!/bin/bash

s=$(awk '/BEGIN!@#/,/END#@!/' switch.log )


while IFS= read -r line 
do

  h=$(echo "$line" | awk '{$1=$1;print}')
  for i in {0..100}
  do

    zzz=$(echo "$h"  | awk '{print $(NF-$i)}')

    if [ ! -z "$zzz" -a "$zzz" != " " ]; then

      hh=$(echo "$h"  | awk  '{print $(NF-$i)}') 
      echo "$zzz"

      echo  -e  "$zzz" >> ggg.txt
      break
    fi

  done

done <<< "$s"
```

I got

```
BEGIN!@#Ghjk,Ghj
```

Comment: Please do fix your samples in code tags as its not clear as of now. Thank you.

Comment: Also note, since your formatting was unclear, If you intended the input to be a multi-line input, please re-edit the questions and format the input properly. (in that case simple `awk` string-concatenation of `$NF` will do)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `sed` with the normal substitute method storing the text you want to keep as the first two backreferences. For example:

```bash
sed -E 's/^.*(BEGIN[^[:space:]]+).*(kEND[^[:space:]]+)/\1\2/' <<< 'your string`
```

**Example Use/Output**

(**note:** updated to handle whitespace at the end)

```
$ sed -E 's/^.*(BEGIN[^[:space:]]+).*(kEND[^[:space:]]+)/\1\2/' <<< '42 45 47 49 4e 21 40 23 47 68 6a 6b 2c 47 68 6a BEGIN!@#Ghjk,Ghj 6b 45 4e 44 23 40 21 kEND#@!'
BEGIN!@#Ghjk,GhjkEND#@!
```

(**note:** single-quoting the string is required due to `'!'`)

Comment: Indeed `sed` is better suited here

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/[0-9]+[a-z]? +| +//g' input_file
BEGIN!@#Ghjk,GhjkEND#@!
```

Comment: Simple and effective sed

Comment: Yep, nuking the unwanted as an approach is worth the nod as well.

Comment: thans allot , its working... but how :-)

Comment: @ahmedahmed Match either one or more integers followed by a space, one or more intergers with an optional `?` alphabetic character  followed by a space, or just spaces and remove them all.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**, to fix an error:
You have not defined precisely in your question, how the string to be extracted looks like *in general*, but based on your example, this would do:

```
if [[ $line =~ (BEGIN[^ ]+)\ .*([^ ]+END[^ ]+) ]]
then
  substring=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
else
  echo Pattern not found in line 1>&2
fi
```

Comment: Good solution, but you are missing the wanted `'k'` in `"kEND..."`.

Comment: This would be only an issue if the text inbetween could also have an `END` in it.  But actually, my solution is incorrect for a different reason, and I will update my answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : My updated solution now does not incorrectly catch the _6b 45 4e 44 23 40 21_ anymore. I missed this point in my first attempt.

Comment: Cleaner than what I was toying with `[[ $line =~ ^.*(BEGIN[^ ]+).*(kEND[^ ].*)$ ]]`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin :In your approach, maybe a `.*?` between the groups would be better. The main problem of course is that  the question is poorly asked and we really don't **know** how the delimeters look like, and as long as we have to guess, any solution would do which works for the concrete example.

Comment: To make bash happy and accommodate the spaces as you have written, I end up with `[[ $line =~ ^.*(BEGIN[^ ]+)[[:space:]].*([^[:space:]]+END[^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]*$ ]]`. Using the unescaped spaces in the regex results in `-bash: syntax error near .*('` on my box. `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release` (and yes, when I refomatted the question I found the "spaces at the end" -- which was after my comment to you)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: About `[:space:]`: To the best of my knowledge, this catches also other types of white space, such as newlines, tabs, the two japanese space characters, and so on. For this reason, I have written a literal space in my solution. Here too, the problem is the unclear description of the problem.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : Fixed the syntax error. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Yes it does, `[[:blank:]]` is more limited, but will catch more than single spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
 42 45 47 49 4e 21 40 23 47 68 6a 6b 2c 47 68 6a BEGIN!@#Ghjk,Ghj 6b 45 4e 44 23 40 21 kEND#@!
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^[:space:]]*(BEGIN|END)[^[:space:]]*";OFS=""}{$1=$1;print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
BEGIN!@#Ghjk,GhjkEND#@!
```

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK using field pattern (`FPAT`) that field is `BEGIN` or (`|`) `END`, prefixed and suffixed by zero-or-more (`*`) non (`^`)-whitespace (`[:space:]`) characters and output field separator (`OFS`) is empty string, then for each line I do `$1=$1` to trigger line rebuilt and `print` it. If you are sure only space characters are used in line you might elect to replace `[^[:space:]]` using `[^ ]`

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

s=$(awk '/BEGIN!@#/,/END#@!/' switch.log)
echo "$s" > ggg.txt

ss=$(sed -E 's/[0-9]+[a-z]? +| +//g' ggg.txt )
echo "$ss" > ddd.txt

sss=$(awk '{print $1}' ddd.txt)
echo "$sss"  > hhhh.txt

ssss=$(awk '/BEGIN!@#/,/END#@!/' hhhh.txt)
echo  "$ssss"  > hhh.txt

aaa=$(<hhh.txt)
aaa=$(cat hhh.txt | tr -d '\n' )

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guidline to improve your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the `awk` *record* separator `RS` to `" "`, `awk` processes a white-spaced-separated portion of your file at a time (with each record containing only one field). So the two parts that are needed can be extracted with simple `awk` condition patterns `/BEGIN/` and `/END/`. There can be no white space in any record since this was the delimiter.

If printed, the pattern-filtered records would normally be separated by a new line (the default output record-separator `ORS`) but this can be changed to an empty string `ORS=""` to make the two print statements run into one another with no space.

Thus this simple `awk` command will return the required fields as a concatentated string with no white space:

```
awk ' BEGIN{RS=" ";ORS=""} /BEGIN/{print} /END/{print}' file.txt
```

output:

```
BEGIN!@#Ghjk,GhjkEND#@!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -oE '(BEGIN|END)\S*' file | paste -sd'\0'

BEGIN!@#Ghjk,GhjEND#@!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ' 42 45 47 49 4e 21 40 23 47 68 6a 6b 2c 47 68 '   \
     '6a BEGIN!@#Ghjk,Ghj 6b 45 4e 44 23 40 21 kEND#@!' |
```

> ```
> {m,g}awk NF=NF FS='[ \t]*([^ \t][^ \t][ \t]+)+[ \t]*' OFS=
> ```

```
BEGIN!@#Ghjk,GkEND#@!
```